# Remove Country Dropdown at Frontend

Tags: dropdown-attribute

Besides using CSS trick (display:none), is there an alternative to remove country dropdown across all frontend pages simply modifying one configuration file or record in database?

Comment: there is language and website dropdown by default in header section magento. Where did you see country selection ?

Comment: No, I did not active language or website selection in my web store, bcause I thought that only selling within my country. Country selection appears at Account > Address, Cart, and Onepage Checkout pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the dropdown by selecting only one country in the admin, but there is no actual way to remove it completely since its a required attribute for the customer object.

Comment: I tried selected only one country in all multiple selects under Configuration > General. But no lucks.

Comment: What do you mean by no luck? That should have showed you only one country in the frontend.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought that the dropdown can be removed (or hide) in the frontend.

Comment: No, not without code. The closest you can get is to have only one country.